# Format AWS CLI output as *markdown* table

Tags: amazon-web-services, markdown

I am trying to format the AWS CLI table output so that it shows as a 'nice' formatted table in markdown in typora, github md files, etc...

For example, the original table-formatted output from the  AWS CLI command

```sh
$ aws ec2 describe-subnets --query "Subnets[*].{CIDR:CidrBlock,Name:Tags[?Key=='Name']|[0].Value,AZ:AvailabilityZone}" --output table
```

is

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|                           DescribeSubnets                          |
+------------+------------------+------------------------------------+
|     AZ     |      CIDR        |               Name                 |
+------------+------------------+------------------------------------+
|  eu-west-3c|  10.1.103.0/24   |  vpc-acme-test-public-eu-west-3c   |
|  eu-west-3b|  172.31.16.0/20  |  None                              |
|  eu-west-3a|  10.1.101.0/24   |  vpc-acme-test-public-eu-west-3a   |
|  eu-west-3c|  10.1.3.0/24     |  vpc-acme-test-private-eu-west-3c  |
|  eu-west-3b|  10.1.2.0/24     |  vpc-acme-test-private-eu-west-3b  |
|  eu-west-3a|  172.31.0.0/20   |  None                              |
|  eu-west-3c|  172.31.32.0/20  |  None                              |
|  eu-west-3a|  10.1.1.0/24     |  vpc-acme-test-private-eu-west-3a  |
|  eu-west-3b|  10.1.102.0/24   |  vpc-acme-test-public-eu-west-3b   |
+------------+------------------+------------------------------------+
```

Based on assorted markdown tutorials and tests, the output that would render properly as a table in typora and github is something like:

```
|     AZ     |      CIDR        |               Name                 |
|------------|------------------|------------------------------------|
|  eu-west-3c|  10.1.103.0/24   |  vpc-acme-test-public-eu-west-3c   |
|  eu-west-3b|  172.31.16.0/20  |  None                              |
|  eu-west-3a|  10.1.101.0/24   |  vpc-acme-test-public-eu-west-3a   |
|  eu-west-3c|  10.1.3.0/24     |  vpc-acme-test-private-eu-west-3c  |
|  eu-west-3b|  10.1.2.0/24     |  vpc-acme-test-private-eu-west-3b  |
|  eu-west-3a|  172.31.0.0/20   |  None                              |
|  eu-west-3c|  172.31.32.0/20  |  None                              |
|  eu-west-3a|  10.1.1.0/24     |  vpc-acme-test-private-eu-west-3a  |
|  eu-west-3b|  10.1.102.0/24   |  vpc-acme-test-public-eu-west-3b   |
```

(the text above does not render as a table in stackoverflow. Below a screenshot of this table rendered in typora:
[image: modified AWS output table as seen in typora]

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any AWS CLI option,  but the following unix-like series of filters does the job.

Pipe the output of the AWS command to:

```sh
sed s/'+'/'|'/g | tail -n +4 | head -n -1
```

The full CLI command is:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-subnets --query "Subnets[*].{CIDR:CidrBlock,Name:Tags[?Key=='Name']|[0].Value,AZ:AvailabilityZone}" --output table  | sed s/'+'/'|'/g | tail -n +4 | head -n -1
```

Other suggestions welcome!